# JQuery combo box and JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am trying to use [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/combobox) from JQuery, however how do I populate the options of the selection of the combo box? I am pretty new to JQuery so some help would be appreciated

So say I have a html code as follows:

```
<select name = "test">
   <option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

what should I do to make it so I have the interface above?

Comment: How to populate the select options? This just restyles the default html dropdown: "unobtrusive way of creating a HTML type combobox from a existing HTML Select element(s)."

Comment: but in the example they give, they don't have a <select> tag in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the example on [this page](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycomboboxexamplebasic.aspx).

You still create an html select element with child options.  Then you turn it into a jquery combobox with either a really simple $('#comboboxid').combobox().  If you want, I can help you with the more advanced options.

Comment: are you saying that all I have to do is to convert my <select> into a combo box and I'll have those effects?

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin only enhances the look'n'feel of a HTML `<select>` element with customizeable CSS styles. It doesn't require any changes to standard HTML/JSP/whatever code you're using to populate the options. You can just write down the dropdown options the usual way in JSP as you would do without this jQuery plugin.

By the way, that plugin is pretty old and its name is fairly misleading. A combobox is in essence an *editable dropdown*. But this plugin does nothing about that at all. What's actually your functional requirement? Aren't you looking at the wrong plugin?

---

**Update**: as to how to use it, just include the [required](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx) JS files in `<head>` and call `$(selector).combobox()` during document load. There's even a complete example [here](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycomboboxexamplebasic.aspx) (note that you need to click the "click to view/hide" link to see the HTML).

Comment: but if I look at the index.html page they have on the demo, they don't have a select tab there?

Comment: It is there. This plugin just transforms its appearance by JavaScript/jQuery. Check the `<select id="officeItemList">` element in HTML source. It's clearly a standard HTML `<select>` element.

Comment: I just want a nice drop down list with auto search capability

Comment: I was talking about [this example](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/samples/example.htm). Further, this plugin doesn't provide auto search capability. I'd suggest adding another one like Flexselect or Quickselect.